# pstricks: How to use adjustbox (or alternative) with pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, adjustbox

When I use an `adjustbox` around anything drawn with `pstricks`, the `adjustbox` just gets ignored. `scalebox` works, but requires manual tuning to determine the proper scaling factor (e.g., to scale something down so that it fits inside the margins, but no further). The following MWE illustrates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.25pt](-6,2)(25,2)
    \end{adjustbox}
    
    \scalebox{0.5}{
        \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.25pt](-6,2)(25,2)
    }
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:
[image]

Notice that the top line, which has the `adjustbox` around it, goes all the way to the page margins, while the identical lower line does not due to the `scalebox` around it. However, it is tricky to manually determine the right scaling factor to make a `scalebox` fit content precisely within the text area.

I do not want to scale images *up* to the text width; I just want to scale them *down* to no more than `\textwidth` if they exceed it. Is there a way to either make `adjustbox` work with `pstricks` drawings, or some alternative? I know `adjustbox` works with `tikzpicture`s, but I specifically want to use `pstricks` for some things I'm doing.

Comment: your scalebox is intended by paragraph indent, and has a space before the rule, so two lots of white space at the left. but I think you want resizebox to textwidh not scalebox

Comment: Ah, good point about the `parindent`. But the issue's still there if I add a `\noindent` in front of the `scalebox`. I've also just tried using `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}`, which produces a blank page (when the line inside `adjustbox` is commented out). Using `\resizebox{\textwidth}{\textheight}{...}` gives me the error `Package graphics Error: Division by 0`. Even if I could get `resizebox` working, wouldn't it scale the image _up_ to `\textwidth`? I don't want to scale anything up, just _down_ if it's too big.

Comment: All PSTricks objects have a width of 0pt. So it makes no sense to use a box command. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: My actual use case is using `pst-jtree` to draw syntax trees on slides. Some of the trees I want to draw can get a bit too wide or tall for the slides. I'd like to use `adjustbox` to scale them down to fit within the text width and text height, without having to run several compilations using `\scalebox` to manually determine the scaling factor, since having several trees can make each compilation take multiple minutes.

Comment: The fp package comes to my mind to solve yor problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-jtree}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\jtree
\! = <left>{A}!a ^<right>{B}.
\!a = <left>{C}!a ^<right>{D}.
\!a = <left>{E} ^<right>{F}.
\endjtree
\end{adjustbox}


\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\psset{unit=15cm}% will be greater than text width
\jtree
\! = {A}
<vert>{\psframebox{B}}
:{C}{D}.
\endjtree
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

For the last example I didn't change the font size which depends not to the PSTricks scaling. This is the reason why it looks a bit curious ... :-)

[image]